# Binary search not working

Tags: scala, binary-search-tree

Below is a binary search algorithm but its not finding the value :

I don't think this algorithm is correct?

'theArray' is initialised to an array of 0's with item at position 7 equal to 4.

```
object various {

  //O(log N)

  def binarySerachForValue(value : Int) = {

    var arraySize = 100
    var theArray = new Array[Int](arraySize)
    theArray(7) = 4
    var timesThrough = 0
    var lowIndex = 0
    var highIndex = arraySize - 1

    while(lowIndex <= highIndex){
        var middleIndex = (highIndex + lowIndex) / 2

        if(theArray(middleIndex) < value)
            lowIndex = middleIndex + 1
        else if(theArray(middleIndex) > value)
            highIndex = middleIndex - 1

        else {
            println("Found match in index " + middleIndex)
            lowIndex = highIndex + 1
        }

        timesThrough = timesThrough + 1

    }

    timesThrough
  }                                               //> binarySerachForValue: (value: Int)Int
    binarySerachForValue(4)                       //> res0: Int = 7
}
```

Comment: Binary search works only if the array/collection item were already sorted. In your case, you have an array of 100 elements all filled with zeroes with only the 7th index as 4. Besides, your code has a very imperative feel. If you're writing in Scala, you're encouraged to write it as "functionally" oriented as possible. Look at [cmbaxter's solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18775928/205936) for an idea.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your array is already properly sorted, you could write your search function a little more functionally using tail optimized recursion as follows:

```
def binarySearchForValue(value : Int, theArray:Array[Int]) = {        
  @tailrec
  def doSearch(arr:Array[Int], index:Int = 0):Int = {        
    val middleIndex = arr.size / 2
    val splits = arr.splitAt(middleIndex)
    val totalIndex = middleIndex + index
    arr(middleIndex) match{
      case i if i == value => totalIndex
      case i if i < value => doSearch(splits._2, totalIndex)
      case _ => doSearch(splits._1 dropRight(1), totalIndex)
    }
  }
  doSearch(theArray)
}
```

Note that this could also be accomplished slightly differently as follows:

```
def binarySearchForValue(value : Int, theArray:Array[Int]) = {        
  @tailrec
  def doSearch(low:Int, high:Int):Int = {
    val mid = (low + high) / 2
    if(mid >= theArray.size) -1 
    else {
        val currval = theArray(mid)
        if (currval == value) mid
        else if (currval < value) doSearch(mid+1, high)
        else doSearch(low, mid - 1)
    }
  }
  doSearch(0, theArray.size)
}
```

Comment: your code causes does not seem to work as below implementation illustrates ? :   binarySerachForValue(7 , Array(2,3,5,6,7,8))     //> res0: Int = 1

Comment: @user470184, that's because we lose track of the exact array index position in successive iterations since we cut down the array in half.  Better way would be to just use lower and upper bounds for search. [Here's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_search#Recursive) the algorithm.

Comment: @cmbaxter, I went ahead and made an edit to your post. If my edit is any good, it should appear shortly.

Comment: @cmbaxter, can you please add a sample binsearch algorithm from [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/6562186) for posterity? None of the other answers show a recursive binsearch algorithm functionally oriented from a Scala perspective.

Comment: @S.R.I, I fixed my solution and also posted yours as well.

Answer (score 0):

loop should be like this:

```
while(lowIndex <= highIndex){
    //note the lowIndex + other
    var middleIndex = lowIndex + ((highIndex + lowIndex) / 2)

    if(theArray(middleIndex) < value)
        lowIndex = middleIndex + 1
    else if(theArray(middleIndex) > value)
        highIndex = middleIndex - 1

    else return middleIndex 

    timesThrough = timesThrough + 1

}
// if loop finished and not returned middleIndex in last else, return -1 (not found)
return -1
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like a proper implementation of the Binary Search Algorithm, but you are providing an array of 0's, with just one number at the index of 7.  Binary Search usually takes an array of sorted values (although you can implement sorting as the first step).

Here is an example of why you need a sorted array first:

Searchfor(4)

theArray = [0,4,0,0,0]

First iteration, look at theArray(2), which equals 0.  0 < 4, so use the upperhalf(i.e. lower index = middleindex + 1

newArray = [0,0]

Then we iterate again and eventually exit the loop because we never found it.  With a sorted list, your technique would work well.

With finding a single value in an array of 0's, your best bet is to just iterate through the array until you find it.  Best of Luck.